# SQLGrammarException: could not execute native bulk manipulation query error

Tags: mysql

I am executing below queries in one function but getting "SQLGrammarException: could not execute native bulk manipulation query error" exception.

Can any one tell me solution for it? I don't want to use HQL .

```
    query = session.createSQLQuery("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp select `"+xAxis+"`, sum(value) as length from (select * from "+xAxis+"Table union select `"+xAxis+"`, sum(cycles) as value from "+Constants.TABLE_NAME+" where datestamp >= '"+startDate+"'  and datestamp < '"+endDate+"'  and `"+groupBy+"` = '"+groupByBar1+"' and `"+xAxis+"` = 'Uptime' group by `"+xAxis+"`) as t group by `"+xAxis+"` "+fixOrderString+" ;CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test select `"+xAxis+"`, sum(value) as length from (select * from "+xAxis+"Table union select `"+xAxis+"`, sum(cycles) as value from "+Constants.TABLE_NAME+" where datestamp >= '"+startDate+"'  and datestamp < '"+endDate+"' and  `"+xAxis+"` = 'Uptime' group by `"+xAxis+"`) as t group by `"+xAxis+"` "+fixOrderString+" ;alter table test add column `"+groupByBar1+"` INTEGER ;");  
            query.executeUpdate();              
            query = session.createSQLQuery("update test,temp set `"+groupByBar1+"` = temp.length where test.`"+xAxis+"` = temp.`"+xAxis+"` ; drop table temp ; CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp select `"+xAxis+"`, sum(value) as length from (select * from "+xAxis+"Table union select `"+xAxis+"`, sum(cycles) as value from "+Constants.TABLE_NAME+" where datestamp >= '"+startDate+"'  and datestamp < '"+endDate+"' and  `"+groupBy+"` = '"+groupByBar2+"' and `"+xAxis+"` = 'Uptime' group by `"+xAxis+"`) as t group by `"+xAxis+"` "+fixOrderString+"  ;alter table test add column `"+groupByBar2+"` INTEGER ; ");
            query.executeUpdate();
            query = session.createSQLQuery("update test,temp set `"+groupByBar2+"` = temp.length where test.`"+xAxis+"` = temp.`"+xAxis+"` ; drop table temp ; CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp select `"+xAxis+"`, sum(value) as length from (select * from "+xAxis+"Table union select `"+xAxis+"`, sum(cycles) as value from "+Constants.TABLE_NAME+" where datestamp >= '"+startDate+"'  and datestamp < '"+endDate+"' and  `"+groupBy+"` = '"+groupByBar3+"' and `"+xAxis+"` = 'Uptime' group by `"+xAxis+"`) as t group by `"+xAxis+"` "+fixOrderString+"  ;alter table test add column `"+groupByBar3+"` INTEGER ;");
            query.executeUpdate();
            query = session.createSQLQuery("update test,temp set `"+groupByBar3+"` = temp.length where test.`"+xAxis+"` = temp.`"+xAxis+"` ; drop table temp ; CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp select `"+xAxis+"`, sum(value) as length from (select * from "+xAxis+"Table union select `"+xAxis+"`, sum(cycles) as value from "+Constants.TABLE_NAME+" where datestamp >= '"+startDate+"'  and datestamp < '"+endDate+"' and  `"+groupBy+"` = '"+groupByBar4+"' and `"+xAxis+"` = 'Uptime' group by `"+xAxis+"`) as t group by `"+xAxis+"` "+fixOrderString+"  ;alter table test add column `"+groupByBar4+"` INTEGER ;");
            query.executeUpdate();
            query = session.createSQLQuery("update test,temp set `"+groupByBar4+"` = temp.length where test.`"+xAxis+"` = temp.`"+xAxis+"` ; drop table temp ; CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp select `"+xAxis+"`, sum(value) as length from (select * from "+xAxis+"Table union select `"+xAxis+"`, sum(cycles) as value from "+Constants.TABLE_NAME+" where datestamp >= '"+startDate+"'  and datestamp < '"+endDate+"' and  `"+groupBy+"` = `"+Constants.OTHERS+"' and `"+xAxis+"` = 'Uptime' group by `"+xAxis+"`) as t group by `"+xAxis+"` "+fixOrderString+"  ;alter table test add column `"+Constants.OTHERS+"' INTEGER ;");
            query.executeUpdate();
            query = session.createSQLQuery("update test,temp set `"+Constants.OTHERS+"` = temp.length where test.`"+xAxis+"` = temp.`"+xAxis+"`;");
            query.executeUpdate();
            query = session.createSQLQuery("select * from test "+fixOrderString+" ;");
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to catch that exception and print it out to see the root cause.
E.g. you can do this with Log4j:

```
log.error("Error", e);
```

The root cause might be that the temporary table created in first statement is not actually seen in the following statements for some reason.